# Using `replace` to put terms under a common denominator with sympy

Tags: sympy

I'm trying to get a subexpression of a larger expression under a common denominator.  However, when I use `replace()` for this, it applies to sums of functions, even though there's no ratio.

```
  >>> x = Function('x')(t)
  >>> f = Function('f')(t)
  >>> g = Function('g')(t)
  >>> a,b = Wild('a'), Wild('b')
  >>> f + g

  f(t) + g(t)

  >>> (f + g).replace(a/x+b/x, (a+b)/x)

  f(t)⋅x(t) + g(t)⋅x(t)
  ─────────────────────
           x(t)
```

How do I get this to apply only where the original source expression has an explicit `/ x(t)` in both terms?

Note: if either f & g, or x, are `Symbol`s, rather than `UndefinedFunction`s, no replacement happens, which is what I want.

Comment: Would it make more sense to collect on the denominator rather than use replace (like `collect(x/z + y/z, z)`)? I might be able to advise better given a slightly less trivial example of the desired replacement.

Comment: If it works with `Symbol`s, as you say, why not replace the Functions with Symbols; perform the Wild replacement; and replace back. Something like `(f + g).xreplace({f: f_symbol, g: g_symbol, x: x_symbol}).replace(a/x_symbol+b/x_symbol, (a+b)/x_symbol).xreplace({f_symbol: f, g_symbol: g, x_symbol: x})`. The only reason I could see this going wrong is if you have instances of `f(t)` and `f(s+t)` in the same expression.

Comment: @OscarBenjamin thanks, `collect(x/z + y/z, z)` was perfect!  On to my next problem.  :)

Comment: Good that it's sorted. I think the original problem might be a bug in sympy. It would be good to report it https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues

Comment: Great sugestion @OscarBenjamin.  Done.  https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/19929